# Short story; Alien soldier uses an Earth soldier's body to train in

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this in an anthology in UK at least forty years ago.
An alien soldier is almost complete in his training and needs to have his final test, this is done by him taking over the body of an Earth soldier during combat. Then he'll be deemed fit to fight his Emperor's enemies.

On Earth a young American recruit is assigned to machine gun duties in a pill box, he's told how to call it in if he sees enemy activity, he asks about some names scratched into the concrete with tick marks beside them. The sergeant points to a tin bucket at the far end of the pillbox, he explains they keep score who can flip a cigarette butt from the observation stool to the bucket - he then leaves and the young soldier begins his watch.

After a couple hours he thinks he sees movement so he looks closely and it's a large number of enemy troops charging, he hastily radios and then goes to his gun, then he stiffens in shock as the alien mentally assumes command of his body.
After a couple of seconds adjusting to such unfamiliar eyes and limbs the alien mounts a spectacular defence, with careful placement of shot and zones of fire, then he gets badly wounded but continues until help arrives.

Back across the galaxy the alien triumphantly gets passed as a full warrior, back on Earth the sergeant shakes his head in admiration as they stretcher away his wounded man, then shakes it again when he sees the rookies name scratched into the wall with one tick mark beside it.

(Note: I posted this recently in here but then deleted because I'd got it hopelessly confused with an Asimov short about Kilroy!)